# Why isn't D3 transition working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and having trouble smoothly transitioning between two data sets. Here's a super simplified version of what I have currently:

```
var h = 500;
var w = 500;

var data = [
  10,
  15,
  12,
  9
]

var data_two = [
  6,
  15,
  20,
  19,
  11
]

var vis = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr({
    height: 500,
    width: 500
  })
  .append('g');

function buildChart(data) {
  var square = vis.selectAll('rect')
      .data(data, function(d) { return d }) 

  square
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr({
      x : function(d, i) { return 0 }  
    })

  square
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr({
      height : function(d, i) { return 10 },
      y      : function(d, i) { return i * 15 },
      width  : function(d, i) { return d * 5 },
      x      : function(d, i) { return 0 }
    });

  square
    .exit()
    .remove();
 } 

buildChart(data);

setTimeout(function() {
  buildChart(data_two)
}, 1000)
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ncakby1a/

My desired results are to have the bars smoothly animate to the new widths after a one second delay. Instead, they just jump to the new state and I'm not sure why. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `data` has only 4 parameters?

Comment: D3 should account for that difference. Also, if you make them even the transition still doesn't work.

Comment: What transition are you expecting to happen? You already have x set as 0 and your transition you are setting x as 0 it would not move anywere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're `buildChart` function is always placing new bars, it's never updating the bars you placed with `data` according to the data in `data_two`. To fix this, first append the rectangles using `data`, then select them & apply the transition:

```
var h = 500;
var w = 500;

var data = [
  10,
  15,
  12,
  9,
  3
]

var data_two = [
  6,
  15,
  20,
  19,
  11
]

var vis = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr({
    height: 500,
    width: 500
  })
  .append('g');

vis.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr({
        x: function(d, i){ return 0;},
        y: function(d, i){ return i * 15;},
        height: function(d){ return 10;},
        width: function(d){ return d * 5;}
    })

vis.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data_two)
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .delay(1000)
  .attr({
     x: function(d, i){ return 0;},
     y: function(d, i){ return i * 15;},
     height: function(d){ return 10;},
     width: function(d){ return d * 5;}
  });
```

Here's a working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncakby1a/2/)